# remove RDF triple having object as nan URIRef

Tags: python, rdf, rdflib

The RDF graph I created from CSV file contains some of the triples like
`prefix1:subject prefix2:hasState prefix1:nan` - As I have converted all the empty fields of **CSV file** to **nan** through `csv_data = csv_data.fillna("nan")` - After that the rdf triples looked like the one I mentioned. Now I want to remove these triples through `g.remove((None, None, URIRef("nan")))`, but unfortunately it does not remove these triples out of the graph. Any help please?

Comment: `URIRef("nan")` is obviously not the same as `prefix1:nan` or how do you think `rdflib` can guess the URI resp. the prefix?

Comment: I expect that all the triples having its *Object* in the *URI* form equal to *nun* be removed.

Comment: ??? you have triples with `prefix1:nan` as object. And you want to remove triples with `URIRef("nan")` - there is no prefix declaration here. Do you understand that there is a difference between "nan" and "prefix1:nan"? `URIRef` expects a full URI as argument, prefixed URIs can be created via namespaces: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/namespaces_and_bindings.html

Comment: thanks, I understand.